# How I can get data using background service in android?

Tags: android

[image]

I am writing this service but it don't work
I want to know that,
When My application install on android device I want to get data from other application ,when other application uses the clipboard
So I have to get that data which is copied to clipboard(but copy perform in other application).
e.g. like copy bubble application
Please help me to how to write background service

Comment: Post code whatever have you try.

Comment: See this https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: M tried OnPrimaryClipChangedListener but it not gives me data when my application is closed from mobile task manager so how I can get the data when my app is closed by mobile task manager  how i can write the background service

Comment: i don't  know how to share my code so m attached the image of my code so please give me solution  its urgent

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

[OnPrimaryClipChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#addPrimaryClipChangedListener%28android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener%29)

how i wrote a service once is like this:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

Notification notification;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
NotificationManager notificationManager;


@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("some text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.someIcon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


Log.e("service", "Started");
    startForeground(99, notification);

//do your stuff here

return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    } 
}
```

then start it with using intent:

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundService.class));
```

i didn't try this code but i think it should work ;)

succes !

Comment: M tried OnPrimaryClipChangedListener but it not gives me data when my application is closed from mobile task manager so how I can get the data when my app is closed by mobile task manager  how i can write the background service

Comment: @Anil i added some code how you can create an background service :p let me know if it works